# Character array in MASM

Tags: arrays, winapi, masm

I have some code and I use WinAPI, It's GUI application.

In data section:

```
procTemplateBuf     db      "%s", 0
modulTemplateBuf    db      "ba: 0x%08X, bs: 0x%08X, %s", 0
procBuf             db      128 dup(0)
modulBuf            db      128 dup(0)
```

And other part, where I try to add `procBuf` in my list box, but I have even one character.

Add:

```
invoke wsprintf, offset procBuf, offset procTemplateBuf, offset PROCDATA.szExeFile

push offset procBuf
push 0
push LB_ADDSTRING
push [LISTBOXPROCESSES]
```

I have this:

[image]

How can I get all string?

Comment: That's what you get when you interpret UTF-16 as ASCII/ANSI/UTF-8.

Comment: Why? I use call SendMessageW@16. There is a postfix 'W', It means, that I use wchar_t. Or not?

Comment: And now I treid to use SendMessageA@16 for ASCII. But It doesn't work still

Comment: `SendMessageW` doesn't decide, whether a window is a Unicode window or not. The call to `RegisterClassExA` or `RegisterClassExW` is what establishes this property. You need to provide a [mcve]. And since you seem to be struggling with both assembly as well as the Windows API, you may want to consider learning one at a time. Try to implement this in C first, and then convert it to assembly (if you have a reason to use assembly).

Comment: Yes, I realised. I've used RegisterClassExA and changed all my functions. Now, I have this: `procTemplateBuf  db  '%s', '%d', 0`

But still, I have one character in string. I wrote `%s`, where is mistake?

Comment: If you want to know, where the problem is, you're going to have to provide a [mcve].